# Java SSL SSLHandshakeException handshake_failure

Tags: java, ssl, sslhandshakeexception

I am using java 8 and requesting with SSLSocket this url:
https://www.flixbus.de/sites/default/files/6_jetzt_buchen_button_tiny.png

I always get a handshake error.
socket.setEnabledProtocols() to force use of a specific protocol didn't help.

Btw, all other web servers work fine. So it's probably not related to my code.

This error also occurs without any ssl/tls protocol restriction.

Any ideas?

The output with option "javax.net.debug=all" is as follows:

```
DEBG getSecureScocket: Supported protocols:
- SSLv2Hello
- SSLv3
- TLSv1
- TLSv1.1
- TLSv1.2
DEBG getSecureScocket: Enabled protocols:
- TLSv1.2
Http Client, setSoTimeout(120000) called
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false

%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1426330417 bytes = { 229, 161, 185, 11, 136, 85, 35, 88, 166, 144, 191, 126, 10, 196, 215, 241, 43, 190, 221, 246, 240,
217, 82, 29, 180, 106, 35, 253 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_
AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH
_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_A
ES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WIT
H_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WIT
H_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_12
8_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1,
secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r
2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA25
6withRSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, MD5withRSA
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 193
[Raw write]: length = 198
[Raw read]: length = 5
[Raw read]: length = 2
Http Client, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
Http Client, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
Http Client, called closeSocket()
Http Client, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
Http Client, called close()
Http Client, called closeInternal(true)
Http Client, called close()
Http Client, called closeInternal(true)

Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.OutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        [...]
```

Comment: Have you tried by enabling all the supported protocols and not just TLSv1.2? just to see if that's the problem (because as you probably already know, SSLvX is not reccomended to be used in production any more)

Comment: Yes. First I used defaults with all protocols enabled. Doesn't work either. 
I found this solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682957/why-does-javas-sslsocket-send-a-version-2-client-hello/4686924#4686924). That's why I restricted protocols and hoped it would help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The site requires [SNI (server name indication)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication), that is without SNI the handshake will fail. All modern browsers support SNI, but not all SSL stacks in programming languages support SNI or use it by default. See http://www.vimino.com/2014/01/jep-114-tls-sni-extension-sunjsse-behavior-changes/ for how to use SNI with Java 8.

You can check for this kind of behavior with `openssl s_client`:

```
# without SNI
$ openssl s_client -connect www.flixbus.de:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
140612985652896:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s23_clnt.c:770:
....
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)

# with SNI
$ openssl s_client -connect www.flixbus.de:443  -servername 'www.flixbus.de'
CONNECTED(00000003)
...
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
```

Or you could use [analyze.pl](https://github.com/noxxi/p5-ssl-tools/blob/master/analyze-ssl.pl):

```
$ perl analyze-ssl.pl  www.flixbus.de
-- www.flixbus.de port 443
 * maximum SSL version  : TLSv1_2 (SSLv23)
 ...
 * SNI supported        : SSL upgrade fails without SNI
```

Comment: Thanks so much for pointing out this (new) SNI extension. This really solved the problem.

Comment: @steffen-ullrich hi, if I run your script, I'm getting `IO::Socket::SSL version 1.984 required--this is only version 1.31 at analyze-ssl.pl line 10.`. Any hints for a non-perler?

Comment: @injecteer:  Version 1.31 you use is more than 5 years old so I guess you somehow need to get a newer version. If you are on windows the latest Strawberry Perl should include what you need. If you are on Linux most recent distributions contain what you need.

Comment: How were you able to determine this site requires SNI?

Comment: @heez: using the tool I've mentioned in the answer. But you can also use [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html).

Answer (score 0):

This error maybe the server not support Tls1.2 that you use

Comment: I restricted to TLS1.2 because the server replies with TLS1.2. At least that's what I understand from the log.
It also does not work if I dont do any protocol restriction.